# What can a id_rsa.pub file be used for?

Tags: ssh, key-authentication, accounts

What can the `id_rsa.pub` file be used for?

I am working in machine A. I need to have an account in machine B.

Another user from my team asked me for my `id_rsa.pub` (from machine A I suppose) so that he can create a user for me in machine B.

Does this make sense? Is `id_rsa.pub` necessary for this? If so, what does it do?

Answer (score 1):

`id_rsa.pub` contains the public key of your RSA key pair. It may be used to allow you access the machine B over ssh without needing to enter password. To know it works, read [this Security SE question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/23227/how-does-ssh-public-key-authentication-work).